# SQLite saving date 12/31/69?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The dates in my sqlite in android is saving 12/31/69 instead of the actual date. I have this in my db adapter:

```
    + KEY_DATE + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

In my activity i have

```
        Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_DATE)));
        mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
```

When I do a Log.d("Debug", mDateFormat.format(date)) it outputs 12/31/69 what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like an overflow error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mDateFormat` is just a date format - you haven't *used* the value of `date` from the previous line anywhere. You want something like:

```
Log.d("Debug", mDateFormat.format(date));
```

Now that may still give the wrong value - but we can move on to that. It would really help if you'd show more of what's in your adapter than the *partial* statement you've got there. We haven't got nearly enough context.

EDIT: You're calling `getLong`, but you've got a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which looks like it'll come out as *text*:

> If the default value of a column is CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then the value used in the new row is a text representation of the current UTC date and/or time. For CURRENT_TIME, the format of the value is "HH:MM:SS". For CURRENT_DATE, "YYYY-MM-DD". The format for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

It's unclear to me what you'd expect to happen when you fetch that value as a long... according to the documentation, the result is implementation-specific - I *suspect* it's returning 0, giving you a date of the Unix epoch, which would make sense with your output if you're in a time zone west of Greenwich.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put mDateFormat.format(date) and it shwos 12/31/69

Comment: @user1104659: And the rest of the context for the first part of the code in your question? Also see my edit, which I suspect explains things.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

1. you are in a timezone which is GMT minus something (edit: confirmed);
2. the long you return is a number of seconds, which means you must multiply by 1000.

The `Date` constructor takes a number of *milliseconds* since epoch, not seconds.

Try and replace your first line with:

```
Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_DATE)) * 1000);
```

Comment: im in a GMT -5 how can I fix it. I made a mistake in the post cause I was just typing it I shouldve copied it.       Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_DATE)));
      mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

      Log.d("Debug", mDateFormat.format(date));

Comment: As I said -- try and multiply the returned long value by 1000